Does this AMM for NFTs makes any sense?
I have created an automated marked maker contract for NFTs. I think that it is best suitable for launching new NFT collections. Here is the contract source code: https://github.com/simplepools/simplepools/blob/main/simplepools-smartcontracts/SimplePoolsNft1155AMM.sol
The function SimplePoolsNft1155AMM.listNftForAMM accepts nft contract address, tokenId for AMM, number of tokens, ERC20 token for the pair, starting price in the ERC20 token and parameters which specify how the price increases when the NFTs are bought. The function buyNfts buys particular number of NTFs from specified collection. The function sellNfts sells particular number of NFTs from specified collection to the contract and returns ERC20 token from the pair to the seller.
What do you think about this contract and do you see a future for such contract as a base for new platform suitable for launching new NFT collections?
Should I continue working on it, or should I find something else to work on?
Thanks.
